# How to use ffmpeg to split an audio file into HLS-compatible chunks? (mp3 format)

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, http-live-streaming

I've been looking all over the web & StackOverflow, and can't get this to work. I have an audio file that I'd like to split into mp3 files and generate a corresponding m3u8 file.

I've tried this, which was the closest:

```
ffmpeg -i sometrack.wav -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 256k -map 0:0 -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list outputlist.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts 'output%03d.mp3'
```

But all the mp3 files are garbled when I play them.

Comment: Since the output format is mpeg-ts, why is the extension mp3? It should be ts

Comment: Regardless of extension, the audio is garbled, and an HTML `<video>` element won't play the playlist.

Comment: SoundCloud uses HLS and their audio segments end in .mp3 and it works fine.

Comment: Only Safari plays HLS natively. Other browsers require some JS script like hls.js to use MSE and generate fmp4 which is then rendered by the browser.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using hls.js.

Comment: What does the console log for hls.js say?

Comment: No errors, nothing. Not even network issues. Just doesn't play. But I have to mention again, if I open any of the segments in QuickTime, they sound garbled. SoundCloud's segments, however, play just fine. There's something wrong in the ffmpeg process.

Comment: Yes, they are mpegts files, not mp3. VLC, ffplay should play them fine. Change segment_format to mp3 to generate a valid mp3 container.

Comment: Aha, that works! I guess I was confused and thought the .ts files would play as mp3s, due to the `-c:a libmp3lame` codec option. So if I use `mpegts` as the segment format, what format are those .ts files in, if not mp3?

Comment: Codecs and containers are different. Think of codec as the language and container as the medium (notebook, flash cards, scroll..etc). MPEG-TS is a container. MP3 is a codec. `.mp3` files are simple containers meant to contain MP3 codec data. Looks like hls.js looks at the extension and assumes container type.

Comment: Got it, makes sense (kinda like mkv). It works now, perfect! Is it ok to use either `<audio>` or `<video>` with hls.js? (PS, please go ahead and officially answer this Q so I can mark it as the answer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two issues here. FFmpeg normally looks at the extension of the output files to determine output container. However, when the output format is forced `-segment_format` for segment muxer or just `-f format` for most others, ffmpeg will pay heed to that and no longer look at the extension. In this case, segment_format is set to `mpegts` so that's what the output files will be. To ensure valid mp3 files, set segment_format to mp3.

The second issue is that since the extension is mp3, my guess is that hls.js is not able to correctly determine the format of the segments, or it assumes a wrong format and tries to parse them that way. Either way, there should be some messages in the browser console to that effect. See https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/pull/1190 for issues that hls.js has had with format probing.

Comment: Oddly enough, using `-segment_format mp3` and `output%03d.mp3` wound up not working with HLS.js. What _did_ work was `-segment_format mpegts` and `output%03d.ts`.

Full command line: `ffmpeg -y -i file.wav -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 0 -map 0:0 -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list segments.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts 'output%03d.ts'`